# Upgrade to 17.10 ONLY Plasma Works - no Gnome

Tags: gnome, kde, 17.10, plasma, budgie

So I had Ubuntu 17.04, and had installed Gnome, Budgie, and KDE Plasma on it side by side - I like a change of GUI scenery once in a while. Anyway, after upgrading to 17.10 (it's a Dell XPS 9550), now the only DE that works is Plasma. I can't boot in with Gnome or Budgie. If I try, I see the login screen, and after that it just goes to the wallpaper screen for the DE and sits there. No GUI or anything - mouse and wallpaper only. Can't right click, can't see any desktop anything other than a wallpaper picture and a mouse. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install GNOME related packages:
*For those, who can't log in to any shell. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>*

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt install xorg xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-all gnome-core gnome-shell gnome-session
```

and then reboot?